# Autorun predicate

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to define autorun predicate, which will run after loading a file?

Yeah, I know about `swipl -s file.pl -g "main."`, but still looking for something, which can be put in source file `file.pl`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:- initialization(main).
```

Make sure the `main` directive always calls `halt/0`, else you will get a toplevel when it fails. Or put in an unconditional call to `halt/0`:

```
:- initialization(once(((main ; true), halt))).
```

Comment: To make this ISO conforming you would need to write this as a `initialization/1` directive.

Comment: @false I just tried to look up what that does and the SWI help didn't add to my understanding...

Comment: Replace `:- Yourgoals.` by `:- initialization(Yourgoals).`. Writing goals directly as you do means you might collide with system specific directives.